# Dynamic SVG Component

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, ionic2

I would like to implement a `component` that dynamicaly bind a `svg` file, and load his content in the component `template`.

Currently, I tried this way :

**icon.component.ts**

```
...

@Component({
    selector: 'app-icon',
    template: `
        <div [innerHTML]="svgTemplate">
        </div>
    `,
})
export class IconComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() name: string;

    private svgTemplate: string;

    constructor(
        private http: Http
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get(`assets/icon/ic_${this.name}.svg`).map(response => response.text()).subscribe(svg => {
            this.svgTemplate = svg;
        });
    }
}
```

But the `svg` content seems to be escaped (nothing appear in the template `div`).

Here is a content `svg` example :

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Calque_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 52.4 44.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 52.4 44.1;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#444444;}
</style>
<g>
    <g transform="translate(312, 312)">
        <path class="st0" d="M-259.6-312H-312v6.4h52.4V-312z"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(312, 312)">
        <path class="st0" d="M-259.6-293.1H-312v6.4h52.4V-293.1z"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(312, 312)">
        <path class="st0" d="M-259.6-274.3H-312v6.4h52.4V-274.3z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you try to replace the `div` element with an `svg` one ?

Comment: I tried, but same happened (empty `svg` tag).

Comment: What is the svg content? Can you give us a small example?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I edited my post.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58660428/5385623)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular automatically sanitizes HTML [based on its security rules](https://angular.io/guide/security#xss) if the source is potentially untrusted. A lot of the SVG is probably being sanitized including the style rules.

*If you trust the source of the svg* you can bypass this using `DomSanitizer`. Note that this makes you potentially vulnerable to injection attacks, but since you control the server that is serving the svg it's a little less risk than if it were being retrieved from a source you did not control. This doesn't mean there is no risk, however.

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

this.svgTemplate = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(svg);
```

Comment: It's works ! Thanks for the response and the advices about potential vulnerabilities.