# Angular 2 Add SVG inside other SVG

Tags: angular, svg, graph

The goal is to generate a graph dynamically, connected with lines just like the example from the beginning of the linked video.

I want all the event listeners available, and from what i understood from SVG, this should be the sort of thing it is good at. However I cant get it to work with the component factory or with ng-template either.

I want to achieve something like this

```
<svg>
   <svg:g my-other-svg-component [attr.x] ... />  <= dynamically created
   <svg:g my-other-svg-component [attr.x] ... />  <= dynamically created
</svg>
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30li6w62eCo

Comment: where is your linked video?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest [this guide](http://teropa.info/blog/2016/12/12/graphics-in-angular-2.html) about svg manipulation and angular. We use [d3](https://d3js.org/) for such tasks.

Also, there is a similar question out there [with your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722670/how-to-create-an-svg-component-dynamically-in-angular2) maybe.

I personally suggest using `*ngFor`, `*ngIf` structural directives, that must work on every case. I cannot see why you need to embed svg-s, and not have them under each other.

Comment: I am nesting the svg because I can see that, that is how this lib does it https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/, I wanted to avid the structural directives because I could not make it work the way I wanted. However it seems that there are a lot of tags which will make it easier. I will post the solution when I find it.

Comment: It seems that the only way to go is with the structural directives, and using the `ng-template`. From this example https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph/blob/master/src/graph/graph.component.ts